# Cant play adpcm audio file with naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, adpcm

I try to play an adpcm alaw (i think its g.723 adpcm 40) file with NAudio without success.

the file is stereo sample rate is 8000 and the bit depth is 16.

when i try to create the adpcm alaw format with 2 channels i got an acm not possible error.
( the error is because i try to create a SampleCannel and the SampleCannel class force to get pcm or ieefloat. so i call to CreatePcmFormat).

therefore i create it with 1 channel and then i can play it but i hear noise.

vlc can play the file successfully.

Comment: is this a WAV file? You should start by calling WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream

Comment: hi mark I was wait for your abswer;-) yes its a wav file and I call to CreatePcmStream but in the acmFormatSuggeest I was got the acm error if i do it with two channels. if i do it with one channel the acmFormatSuggest works.

Comment: the problem solved. i do the the acmSuggest with one channel and its siunds pretty good. still dont know why two channels give me error. Mark thanks for your NAudio

Comment: lots of low bitrate telephony codecs typically are expecting mono, so the ACM codecs may not accept stereo input